# tkinter's .pack method isn't dividing the space properly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to figure out the Packing order. Book says

> after widgets are given cavity space, expand divides any space left, and fill and anchor stretch and position widgets within their assigned space.

So I wrote the following and can't understand why the West and East labels aren't expanding to sharing some of North's vertical space:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

north = Label(root,text='North', bg='cyan')
north.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

west = Label(root,text='West', bg='red')
west.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

east = Label(root,text='East', bg='green')
east.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Cropped screen-shot of what I see:

[image: Cropped screen-shot of what I see]

[image: Cropped image of what I'd like to see]

Answer (score 0):

When you pack `north` to the top, it is going to take up the full width of the available space. Once you pack something at the top, nothing else will be able to go to the left or right of it (without using some rarely used additional options). When you then pack `west` to the left, it must go below `north`.

Here is the official description of the complete packer algorithm:

> For each master the packer maintains an ordered list of slaves called the packing list. The -in, -after, and -before configuration options are used to specify the master for each slave and the slave's position in the packing list. If none of these options is given for a slave then the slave is added to the end of the packing list for its parent.
>
> The packer arranges the slaves for a master by scanning the packing list in order. At the time it processes each slave, a rectangular area within the master is still unallocated. This area is called the cavity; for the first slave it is the entire area of the master.
>
> For each slave the packer carries out the following steps:
>
> 1. The packer allocates a rectangular parcel for the slave along the side of the cavity given by the slave's -side option. If the side is top or bottom then the width of the parcel is the width of the cavity and its height is the requested height of the slave plus the -ipady and -pady options. For the left or right side the height of the parcel is the height of the cavity and the width is the requested width of the slave plus the -ipadx and -padx options. The parcel may be enlarged further because of the -expand option (see EXPANSION below)
> 2. The packer chooses the dimensions of the slave. The width will normally be the slave's requested width plus twice its -ipadx option and the height will normally be the slave's requested height plus twice its -ipady option. However, if the -fill option is x or both then the width of the slave is expanded to fill the width of the parcel, minus twice the -padx option. If the -fill option is y or both then the height of the slave is expanded to fill the width of the parcel, minus twice the -pady option.
> 3. The packer positions the slave over its parcel. If the slave is smaller than the parcel then the -anchor option determines where in the parcel the slave will be placed. If -padx or -pady is non-zero, then the given amount of external padding will always be left between the slave and the edges of the parcel.
>
> Once a given slave has been packed, the area of its parcel is subtracted from the cavity, leaving a smaller rectangular cavity for the next slave. If a slave does not use all of its parcel, the unused space in the parcel will not be used by subsequent slaves. If the cavity should become too small to meet the needs of a slave then the slave will be given whatever space is left in the cavity. If the cavity shrinks to zero size, then all remaining slaves on the packing list will be unmapped from the screen until the master window becomes large enough to hold them again.

Taken from http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26

From the same documentation it says about expansion (the `expand` attribute):

> Extra horizontal space is distributed among the expandable slaves whose -side is left or right, and extra vertical space is distributed among the expandable slaves whose -side is top or bottom.

---

To get the behavior you want with only using `pack`, start by packing two frames (or two of just about any widget) top and bottom. set the `expand` attribute to `True`. Then, you can have the bottom frame be the master of the red and green frames.

Comment: I had an idea of the above, but it's the expansion paragraph under the source that you gave mean that explained why.

"Extra horizontal space is distributed among the expandable slaves whose -side is left or right, and extra vertical space is distributed among the expandable slaves whose -side is top or bottom."

Unfortunately I don't know how to go around that and get the extra space distributed equally(ish) amongst the widgets...

Comment: @MaxJambon: I don't know what layout  you're expecting, so I don't know how to give you any better advice. _"sharing some of North's vertical space:"_ is just too vague.

Comment: I added a 2nd image of what I'm expecting, basically the West and East share the vertical space with North equally. I've tried to use frames but the result is the same, or the frame itself doesn't stretch when I resize the window.

Comment: @MaxJambon: I added a bit more clarification. If you read the canonical documentation it tells you that when you pack things on the left or right, `expand` will distribute extra space along the horizontal axis.